# MKMapview zoom level within Kilometer

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming, region

i have a application which has 3 things in `UIViewController`

1. MapView
2. Search-control - (Ability to Search any Location in Map view)
3. Slider - (minimum value 0km - Maximum value 50Km)

Now i have Searched one city Lets Say Barcelona . it will search using Geocode method and i got the latitude and Longitude of the Barcelona and i have added one annotation of red Pin which show title and sub locality in annotation click..

i want to calculate distance of Zoom in zoom out with in the Radius of that annotation in Kilometers. what are the best possible way to achieve this ?
For e.g. i want to zoom around 30 km within that Radius

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just use MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance function and then call setRegion.  There must be a hundred questions and answers on SO about this.

Comment: Thanks Anna for helping

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a MKCoordinateRegion with the searched point as the center and 30km(or whatever distance) as the radius,
see  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275605/mkcoordinateregion-distance-between-center-and-borders)  to do it. Set the map region to the calculated value using this method

```
setVisibleMapRect:animated:
```